# How Do I Pass a Function Through A React Component For Data Sharing Between Parent and Child?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have followed this tutorial (https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/pass-data-between-components-in-react/) to the best of my ability but I am still having trouble

I am getting the following error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: childToParent is not a function"
```

Here is the parent function:

```
function App() {
const childToParent =(value) => {console.log(value)}
...
return (
...
  <SelectHours value={state.selectedHour} childToParent={childToParent}></SelectHours>
...
)
```

and the child function:

```
export default function SelectHours(selectedHours, childToParent) {
....
return (
<Select
  labelId="select-demo"
  id='select-demo'
  defaultValue=""
  //onChange={event => handleChange(event.target.value, true)}
  value={workHours[0] ? workHours[0] : ""}
>
  {
    workHours.map((value, index) => {
      return (
        <MenuItem
          value={value ? value : ""}
          key={index}
          onClick={() => childToParent(value)}
        >
          {value}
        </MenuItem>
      )
    })
  }
</Select>
)
....
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add your curly braces so react can tell its a prop.

```
export default function SelectHours({selectedHours, childToParent}) {
....
return (
<Select
  labelId="select-demo"
  id='select-demo'
  defaultValue=""
  //onChange={event => handleChange(event.target.value, true)}
  value={workHours[0] ? workHours[0] : ""}
>
  {
    workHours.map((value, index) => {
      return (
        <MenuItem
          value={value ? value : ""}
          key={index}
          onClick={() => childToParent(value)}
        >
          {value}
        </MenuItem>
      )
    })
  }
</Select>
)
....
}
```

Comment: Did you assign a data to the value variable via state or just as a variable, I mean before you returned the jsx ?

Comment: We posted 2 seconds apart. :)

Comment: I had the wrong name in the components argument

Comment: Awesome glad I could help, you can give this answer the green tick to help others, cheers!

Comment: shoot! it happens, happy coding!

Answer (score 2):

must destruct props like this.

```
export default function SelectHours({selectedHours, childToParent})
```

or use props like this

```
    export default function SelectHours(props)
      ...
    onClick={() => props.childToParent(value)}
```

read about object destructuring in this article

https://dmitripavlutin.com/javascript-object-destructuring/

Comment: God bless you sir.

Answer (score 1):

You need to have a handler for ChildToParent inside

```js
function App() {
...
const childToParent =(value) => {console.log(value)}
return (
...
  <SelectHours value={state.selectedHour} childToParent={childToParent}></SelectHours>
...
)
```

the App component

Comment: I do have that. Sorry, I forgot to add that part. (doing it now)